# Websphere custom exception (WSVR0605W)

Tags: java, exception, websphere, websphere-8

I am getting this Exception in websphere 8 when a method takes a bit longer than configured.

```
[5/16/14 10:48:14:863 CEST] 00000003 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 22" (0000028b) has been active for 662505 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 2 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ...
```

I want to write for this exception custom exception in Java or extend this exception with parameters. Is there a way?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not an exception, this is only a warning. It may be very possible that the thread it warns about still is working on something and will complete later.

Answer (score 0):

There are [JMX notifications](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ctrb_hangdetection.html) that are sent when these messages are sent, but the JMX notifications have the same (or fewer) parameters as the messages, so you're not going to be able to get any more details, but you can implement your own custom actions in addition to the message being printed.  There are several [hung thread detection custom properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/ttrb_confighangdet.html) that can be set to change the builtin behavior.